# Printing words in rows by length and in alphabetical order

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing a program where a data file has multiple lines of words and the words are being printed in rows by their length. For example, if a word has a length of 2 then all of the words from the data file that have a length of 2 are to be put onto that same line. The words need to be sorted by alphabetical order (I assume I can use arrays.sort).

Here is my data file:

```
the jaguar is a wild cat species and only
extant member of genus panthera natives to americas present
range extends from southwestern united_states mexico in north_america
across much south paraguay northern argentina though
there are cats now living within_western has
largely_been extirpated since early_century it listed as near
threatened on red list its numbers declining_threats include loss
fragmentation habitat
```

I cant figure out how to achieve the rows being printed by their word length. I currently made a program that turns the lines in the data file into an array.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bojing {
    static String[] array;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("bojing.dat"));
    while(file.hasNext()) {
        String line = file.nextLine();
        Scanner chop=new Scanner(line);
        while(chop.hasNext()) {
        String word =chop.next();
        }

        String[] str = line.split("\\s+");
        array = new String[str.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
            array[i] = (str[i]);
        }

        Arrays.sort(array);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

        }
    }
}
```

My current output based off of this code:

```
[a, and, cat, is, jaguar, only, species, the, wild]
[americas, extant, genus, member, natives, of, panthera, present, to]
[extends, from, in, mexico, north_america, range, southwestern, united_states]
[across, argentina, much, northern, paraguay, south, though]
[are, cats, has, living, now, there, within_western]
[as, early_century, extirpated, it, largely_been, listed, near, since]
[declining_threats, include, its, list, loss, numbers, on, red, threatened]
[fragmentation, habitat]
```

This is what my output is supposed to look like.

```
a
as in is it of on to
and are cat has its now red the
cats from list loss much near only wild
genus range since south there
across extant jaguar listed living member mexico though
extends habitat include natives numbers present species
americas northern panthera paraguay
argentina
extirpated threatened
largely_been southwestern
early_century fragmentation north_america united_states
within_western
declining_threats
```

Comment: What is `chop`? Doesn't seem to be used. Or rather the `word` extracted from it is unused.

Answer (score 1):

Start by building a `Map<Integer, List<String>>`, where the key is the word length, and the list contains the words of that length, then sort each list as you print them.

If you change the `List` to a `Set`, then any duplicate words are eliminated. If you then use a `TreeMap` for the `Map`, and a `TreeSet` for the `Set`, the result will automatically be sorted by length, and words sorted alphabetically.

You can do this in 2 statements using a try-with-resources and a Stream (Java 9+):

```
try (Scanner file = new Scanner(input)) {
    file.tokens()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length, TreeMap::new,
                    Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new)))
            .values().stream()
            .map(list -> list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" ")))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

*Output*

```
a
as in is it of on to
and are cat has its now red the
cats from list loss much near only wild
genus range since south there
across extant jaguar listed living member mexico though
extends habitat include natives numbers present species
americas northern panthera paraguay
argentina
extirpated threatened
largely_been southwestern
early_century fragmentation north_america united_states
within_western
declining_threats
```

Comment: Learning to assign keys to lists that need sorting is majorly important to understand when you're learning programming. Only issue between this and desired output is that the output is in `Arrays` instead of a printed list of strings as indicated in the question.

Comment: @SentientFlesh Fixed output to match question goal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you need to sort the word list as a whole but you sort each line in itself.

You can add words of each line to a list:

```
Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+")).forEach(word -> list.add(word));
```

Then sort the list first by length, then alphabetically. This way you can get the output you want:

```
list.sort( Comparator.comparing(String::length).thenComparing(String::compareTo));
```

Try this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("bojing.dat"));
while (file.hasNext()) {
    String line = file.nextLine();
    Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+")).forEach(word -> list.add(word));
}

list.sort( Comparator.comparing(String::length).thenComparing(String::compareTo));
// System.out.println(list);
```

To get the desired output:

```
int wordLength = list.get(0).length();
for(String word : list) {
    if(word.length()!= wordLength) {
        wordLength = word.length();
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print(word + " ");
}
```

Output:

```
a 
as in is it of on to 
and are cat has its now red the 
cats from list loss much near only wild 
genus range since south there 
across extant jaguar listed living member mexico though 
extends habitat include natives numbers present species 
americas northern panthera paraguay 
argentina 
extirpated threatened 
largely_been southwestern 
early_century fragmentation north_america united_states 
within_western 
declining_threats
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, best practice is to create `Scanner` only once. Your initial String file is the raw input that's being read, that's all you need the scanner for. Once you've written the file to some data type you can close the Scanner and decide on the logic for sorting.

Take a look at what you did here:

```
String[] str = line.split("\\s+");
        array = new String[str.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
            array[i] = (str[i]);
        }
```

You are splitting the entire line up at whitespace and your `str.length` is the total number of strings in that line. What you are doing is taking each line individually, separating the strings, then placing that line back into a sorted array without any context as to the number of characters in each string.

Breaking the problem down, we need to sort two different things:

1. Group the strings based on the number of characters in each one.
2. Alphabetize each list of strings with character-count = N.

One way to sort objects with key/value pairs - in this case an `Integer` representing the number of characters in each string would be appropriate. The most fundamental way to do this would be to use a map where each key is paired to a list of `String` objects of that length:

```
Map<Integer,List<String>>
```

Once you iterate through your entire word list, you can use `Collections.sort()` to print out each line of strings containing progressively higher character counts. I would highly recommend you look into these classes to gain a fundamental understanding, but an easier way to sort is to use the built in logic of `Collections.sort` and a `Comparator` to take care of both at once.

Use your scanner to read each word in the file (accounting for whitespace), and put it into an `ArrayList`:

```
// Opening our scanner and useDelimiter(whiteSpace) in one line.            
Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("bojing.dat")).useDelimiter("\\s+");
            //Strings in a currently unsorted ArrayList
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>
            // As long as there is another string in your file, we add that string to our list.
            while (file.hasNext()){
                list.add(file.next());
            }
            // Done with scanner, close it.
            file.close();
```

We'll use Collections and a Comparator next to sort and print the list we've created:

```
// Use collections to sort our list, with a Comparator using some rules:            
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                // Comparator evaluates each string according to length
                public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                    if(o1.length() > o2.length()) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        // We want to ignoreCase here, as characters of different case have different values..
                        return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
                    }
                }

            });
            // Our list has been ordered alphabetically, according to string length.
            System.out.println(list);
```

Comparison (in this context) returns a negative number if the first string is shorter, positive if it's larger, and 0 if they're the same length.

`Collections.sort()` takes care of your alphabetical sorting, while the `Comparator<String>()` logic takes care of the relative size of each string being compared. Take a look at the documentation for each of these to get a better understanding of how you are able to do so much with a few lines of code.

With Java8 introducing lambda operators, we can substantially reduce the lines of code - but I think it's more important you understand the fundamentals before skipping to that as it can be confusing at first.